# How can I count features that go in pairs

Tags: python, excel

My data set looks like that: (f denotes features, ID denotes customers)

[image: 1]

I would like to count pairs of features that appear through all the customers IDs.
For example in the above sample as seen I would like to get that (f1,f2) = 3 , (f2,f33)= 2 , (f3,f33)=0 and so on

Comment: Can you please share you code?

Comment: are you sure that (f2,f33)= 2 ? Wouldn't it be (f2,f33)= 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I understood what you want, but this is my suggestion:

```py
import pandas as pd

counter = dict()

df = pd.read_csv("./data.csv")
# iterate over columns
for column_name in list(df.columns):
    column = list(df.loc[:,column_name])
    # iterate over column elements except last one
    for i in range(len(column)-1):
        key = (column[i], column[i+1])
        # if counter exists increment in 1
        if key in counter:
            counter[key] += 1
        # if it does not exist start it with 1
        else:
            counter[key] = 1

print(counter)
```

That outputs:

```
{('f1', 'f2'): 3, ('f2', 'f3'): 1, ('f3', nan): 1, ('f2', 'f4'): 2, ('f4', 'f6'): 1, ('f2', 'f33'): 1, ('f33', nan): 2, ('f4', 'f33'): 1}
```

Just in case anybody else wants to give it a try, the data has been loaded from a CSV file that looks like this:

```
ID1,ID2,ID3,ID4
f1,f1,f1,f2
f2,f2,f2,f4
f3,f4,f33,f33
,f6,,
```